# JDK vs Android SDK (ASDK )?

Tags: java, android, web-applications

I am new to android but has 8 years of experience in java based web apps. I have below questions on ADK while comparison JDK for web based development.

As Android Software Development Kit(ASDK) is used for android development. My question is does ADK also uses internally JRE to execute the server side files  or it 
has separate runtime environment ?

Also how client side programming is done in ADK ? For example in  java based web app we use HTML file to display the UI and JS to trigger the events both executed
by browser ? Do we still use HTML/JS in android app for UI and cient side events os is there a separate mechanism for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is does ADK also uses internally JRE to execute the server side files

There are no server-side files associated with Android apps, unless you decide to do that yourself (e.g., have the app contact a Web service).

> Do we still use HTML/JS in android app for UI and cient side events

You can, through so-called hybrid app frameworks, such as PhoneGap. Android has its own GUI framework, and various other engines exist (e.g., Unity 3D for games).

Comment: I did not get `There are no server-side files associated with Android apps, unless you decide to do that yourself ` ? For example if I place the order through Amazon ecommerce app, there must be some code/files (like servlet/services/DAO classes in java based web app executed by JRE) which must be executed by some run time environment. Is n't it ?

Comment: @emilly: "For example if I place the order through Amazon ecommerce app, there must be some code/files (like servlet/services/DAO classes in java based web app executed by JRE) which must be executed by some run time environment" -- Amazon is responsible for the code running on their servers. You are not. At most, you are responsible for *client side code* that talks to Amazon's client-side library or Web service endpoint.

Comment: @commonWare  In this example I am considering myself as amazon who is developing say ecommerce mobile app from scratch. As  amazon I need to develop both client side part and server side part(responsible for  server side like processing the order).  Do you mean here when we talk mobile app development(android). Android development  is  about client side  part (like UI, client side processing, communicating with ). Server side part does not come under android development and it can be implemented in any language like  web service end points or servlets or PHP etc . Is that you mean here ?

Comment: @emilly: Correct. You are welcome to implement your Web service in whatever language/environment/framework you want. The Android SDK, and probably even your code in the Android app, neither knows nor cares what stuff was used to build the Web service. All the app cares about is what the API is that is exposed by that Web service and how to consume that API.

Comment: looks like I start getting it now. It means ASDK is mainly about developing the code at client side(which mean code which runs on mobile) where as when we talk about JDK its mainly about server side code (servlets/dao/business services). I hope its correct :). If yes what is the runtime environment on mobile which executes the android code under app ? Thanks for patience.

Comment: @emilly: "what is the runtime environment on mobile which executes the android code under app" -- that will be Dalvik or ART, depending on OS version.

Comment: Thanks a lot CommonsWare .One last thing  , Basically whenever adroid app
want to communicate with server, it will be http call to server . Now any server process be it webservice end point or servlet can respond to it. I believe
it will be http response  and it will ultimately contain  one of these  html/json/xml. Right?

Comment: @emilly: "I believe it will be http response and it will ultimately contain one of these html/json/xml" -- the HTTP response will contain whatever the Web service developer decides to have the HTTP response contain. For example, Web services can return PNG files, `protobuf`-formatted content, YAML, spreadsheets, PDF files, and so on.

Comment: can you provide your thoughts on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065563/converting-desktop-web-app-to-mobile-app