# converting desktop web app to mobile app?

Tags: java, android, web-applications, mobile-application

I am working on desktop based responsive web application where UI/front end will be in HTML/JS and back end point will be either servlets or struts/spring controllers.

My question is say after 3 years i want to have android mobile app , can 
I continue to use my servlet as back end code and serves the response coming from android mobile app,

**Mine understanding :-** I will develop the native UI part(wherever it is required) using android SDK  which then  can communicate with existing servlets .
Then android app on mobile can render the html returned from my servlets  or servlets can return the android specific views. so changes are required only whenever i need custom views(htmls or android specific views) for my mobile application. Is that right ?

Comment: Sorry, but I think that question is too broad; and is mainly asking for opinion-based answers.

Comment: @GhostCat Primarily mine question is can I continue to use existing servlets. I don't think its based on opinion. It should be either yes or no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after 3 years... can I continue to use my servlet as back end code and serves the response coming from android mobile app

We have no way of predicting the future with accuracy.

> Then android app on mobile can render the html returned from my servlets

To render HTML in Android, you use `WebView` (or *maybe* a third-party library, though that is uncommon). `WebView` handles lots of stuff but not everything that a desktop browser does. How well that all works three years from now is unknown, and how well it works today with whatever your Web site does is unknown.

> or servlets can return the android specific views

No.

> so changes are required only whenever i need custom views(htmls or android specific views) for my mobile application

Can you get that to work? Possibly, but the details will depend a lot on what your existing Web site does and what sorts of client-side technologies it depends upon. For example, Android does not support Flash. There are also technical and security issues with interoperating between Java based UIs and `WebView`-based UIs, though this is a bit better in your case, as you are only hitting one server (I think).

All that being said, I would never write an Android app this way, and I would never recommend anyone else write an Android app this way. I would revise the Web server to have a proper Web service API, and I would write a native Android app that uses that Web service API, not using servlets returning HTML. The primary place where I would use `WebView` is when I had material that only exists in HTML, typically because I did not create the HTML in the first place (e.g., user-generated content).

> Primarily mine question is can I continue to use existing servlets. I don't think its based on opinion. It should be either yes or no

Of course it is not "yes or no". We have no way of predicting the future, and we know almost nothing about the Web site. Your question collected two "too broad" close votes, and that is a reasonable assessment.

Comment: Thanks . You said `..I would write a native Android app that uses that Web service API, not using servlets returning HTML`. Got it that its better to write native android app. But what response format webservice api  supposed to send in place of HTML ? I mean say I hit getEmployees button from android app where my app need to display data in different View/UI say in tabular format/or some other fancy stuff. I understand webservice api will returns all employee data but what about UI view. Will android app will have it already at client side(in mobile) or webservice api needs to send it ?

Comment: If webservice api need to send it , what is format android expects(looks like its not html)? In java based web app we generally send html response filled with data

Comment: @emilly: "But what response format webservice api supposed to send in place of HTML ?" -- usually, a Web service returns JSON or XML. You can read more about [Web services on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service). "Will android app will have it already at client side(in mobile)" -- yes.

Comment: I know webservices returns usually XML or JSON. But mine question is when some  UI viewpage need to be returned from server , what form it will be ? But I think  you are saying all views should already present at client side(mobile), so ideally there should not be any need to send UI page from server/web service. I think you already said yes but making my question more clear here so that concept is clear ?

Comment: @emilly: "But I think you are saying all views should already present at client side(mobile), so ideally there should not be any need to send UI page from server/web service" -- correct. This is how most user-facing software gets written (Windows desktop, OS X desktop, Linux desktop, iOS mobile, Android mobile, etc.). The browser-based Web is the dominant modern example of "the UI is pushed from a server".

Comment: Thanks . I posted another question specifically comparing the mobile app with web based applications at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191037/android-app-communication-with-web-server. Somehow I assumed mobile apps are also like thin clients on mobile where all data including UI is fetched from server. But its clear I am wrong here.